# cPanel my filesystem.php automatic delete

Tags: laravel, cpanel

When I upload my Laravel project on cPanel my filesystem.php automatic remove.

> Warning: include(): Failed opening
>   '/home/xxx/public_html/Servisler/KelimeOyunu/vendor/composer/../laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php'
>   for inclusion
>   (include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/share/pear') in
>   /home/xxx/public_html/Servisler/KelimeOyunu/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php
>   on line 444

Answer (score 0):

Are you uploading the vendor folder with your project? If yes, try deleting the vendor folder from the server, and then installing your dependancies fresh with
`composer install`